# Java detect rotation in image

Tags: java, image, rotation, ocr, detect

I am working on an OCR which main function is to OCR invoices, now it can happen that they have a (slight) rotation when being scanned.

What would you suggest to fix the rotation?

What I currently have:

- A function that calculates the "amount of white lines" in the image.
- A function that can rotate the image by any angle.
- Current approach: Rotate the image by an angle of 1 degree every time, check the solution with the most white lines, and use that image for the rest of the OCR process.
- The downside: Every rotation takes 0.5 seconds, the images are scanned in a fairly reasonable high resolution (2000 width x 3000 height), and the resolution is definitely needed for the OCR process.

Is there any way I can detect the rotation in the image, such that I only need to do one expensive rotation?

Regards.

Comment: Could You please share idea how are you detecting if image is rotated and rotating back in opposite direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - The downside: Every rotation takes 0.5 seconds, the images are scanned in a fairly reasonable high resolution (2000 width x 3000 height), and the resolution is definitely needed for the OCR process.

Sure, but the high resolution is probably *not needed* in order to analyze the white lines.

I would recommend trying to shrink or crop the image (to a smaller copy) before the first angle determination, and use the low resolution version consistently *until the angle is determined.*  Then swap back to the large resolution image for the final rotation and for the OCR.

Comment: Will definately test the solution soon (tm). But to keep it theoretical, if I cut down the width and height by two, so for a resolution of 1000 width x 1500 height, the time taken should be 0.125 seconds? Again just in theory.

Comment: Re. times/durations.  Yes probably 1/4, if the line algorithm is doing pixel by pixel calculations.

Comment: Interestingly on half resolution it takes 0.015s per try, and on quarter resolution it takes 0.01s per try. While on the full resolution it still takes 0.45s.

Comment: *"on quarter resolution it takes 0.01s per try. While on the full resolution it still takes 0.45s."*  45 times faster!  Not bad.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to first downgrade the image and convert it into `monochrome` so we have only `0 and 255 in the 8 bit` color format that will help in identifying) and then track `black` lines instead of `white` on the invoices(that should not be a big change on your algorithm), as generally invoices contain horizontal black lines so as soon as you can find the slope of the black line(`that are 30 degree +/- to you plane` as i guess input won't be more tilted then that) you can get the degree rotation that you need for the main image.

To optimize the process i would suggest you to also use the image thinning before tracking the black lines, that will get you better results as there may be thick black lines.